# perl Skipping values in array

Tags: perl

I have a text file

```
II : RE: released for CR CHG1001739981 : Urgent for NYK SOD - INC1012082403
CN: RE: futures  - INC1012083269
AP: RE: REQ25116618-1: setups - INC1012084465
DS: RE: access - INC1012084976
LC: RE: options Grid - INC1012085569
II: RE: issues - INC1012085587
VK: RE: FW data - INC1012085827
NW: RE: spread  - INC1012086027
AP: RE: Exception Notification - INC1012087025
VK: RE: Yellow - INC1012087066
DS: RE: Exception Notification - INC1012087664</none>
LC: RE:  - INC1012087915
CN: RE: [Restricted - Internal] - INC1012088249
WJ: FW: issue - INC1012088961
can i get an inc for this pls
you sure can
CN: User Feedback - INC1012089212
thank you
np
CN: benchmark - INC1012089691
DS: NAN Value - INC1012089989
TM:downstream - INC1012090321
re-assigning to myself
II: setup - INC1012090460
LC: size - INC1012090813
BJ - help with filter
**handover mail**
:)
```

This is how tickets are assigned in this group. Most of the team gets here at 7AM, BJ gets here at 10:30 and the
handover to the US is at 11:00. Since BJ just gets in he is often shifted to the top of the queue - he gets the first ticket. 
What I have to do is figure out what the order is for the rest of the shift. Usually by hand I remove the people from england who get off work at 11am easter time.
Then I strip off the test from the remining US people, and put them in horizontal order.

```
II AP DS LC II AP DS LC WJ DS AP II LC BJ
```

then reverse them

```
 BJ LC II AP DS WJ LC DS AP II LC DS AP II
```

then skipping the BJ, go to the [1] in the list in this case LC, and the go back to where we get "LC" again.

```
 BJ LC II AP DS WJ
```

the reverese it again  - and voila you hyave the assignment order for the day.

```
WJ DS AP II LC BJ
```

Right now I am having trouble stopping priting at the first instance of "LC"

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper ;
my @team = ("AP","II","DS","WJ", "JK","LC","BJ") ;
my @orderdTeam ;
my $begin ;
my $rev ;
my @rev_orderdTeam  ;
my $filename = shift @ARGV ;
open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "Could not open file $filename $!";
while (my $line = <$fh> ) {
    foreach my $op (@team) {
        if ($line =~ /$op/) {
        push (@orderdTeam, $op) ;
        }
    }

    }


print "order ---------> " . "@orderdTeam" . "\n"       ;
@rev_orderdTeam = reverse(@orderdTeam)              ;
print "reverse order -> " . "@rev_orderdTeam" . "\n"   ;

print "The last person to get assigned is $begin\n" ;

foreach $rev (@rev_orderdTeam[1 .. $#rev_orderdTeam]) {
    if ("$rev_orderdTeam[0]" eq "BJ") {
           $begin = $rev_orderdTeam[1]
    }
    else {
          $begin = "$rev_orderdTeam[0]" ;
    }

    if ($rev ne "$begin") {
            print "$rev " ;

    }
}
```

Comment: I think there's an error in your example output. There's no `AP` in `TM:downstream - INC1012090321` and `re-assigning to myself`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach using a flag to determine when to extract elements from the order team array:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @team = ("AP","II","DS","WJ", "JK","LC","BJ") ;
my ( $team_regex ) = map {qr /$_/} join "|", map {quotemeta} @team;

my @orderdTeam ;
my $filename = shift @ARGV ;
open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "Could not open file $filename $!";
while (my $line = <$fh> ) {
    if ( $line =~ /^($team_regex)/ ) {
        push @orderdTeam, $1;
    }
}
close $fh;

print "Ordered: @orderdTeam\n";
my $extract_flag = 0;
my @result;
my $end_name;
for my $name (reverse @orderdTeam) {
    if ($name eq "BJ") {
        $extract_flag = 1;
    }
    next if $extract_flag == 0; # skip items until we get "BJ"
    if ( $extract_flag == 2 ) {
        $end_name = $name; # save stop name
    }
    last if $extract_flag == 3 && ($name eq $end_name); # second occurrence of $end_name
    push @result, $name;
    $extract_flag = 3 if $extract_flag == 2;
    $extract_flag = 2 if $extract_flag == 1;
}

print "Result: ", (join " ", reverse @result), "\n";
```

**Output**:

```
Ordered: II AP DS LC II AP DS LC WJ DS II LC BJ
Result: WJ DS II LC BJ
```

Answer (score 2):

Before I start, note that the initial order for the data you provided is

```
II AP DS LC II AP DS LC WJ DS II LC BJ
```

rather than

```
II AP DS LC II AP DS LC WJ DS AP II LC BJ
```

as you claimed.

---

To achieve your goal, I recommend using a different approach than the one you describe. It seems to me that your actual intent is to remove duplicates, and that's what the following solution does:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use List::Util qw( uniq );

my @team = qw( AP II DS WJ JK LC BJ );
my %team = map { $_ => 1 } @team;

my @order;
while (<>) {
   my ($op) = /^(\w+)/
      or next;

   $team{$op}
      or next;

   push @order, $op;
}

my @filtered = reverse uniq reverse @order;
say "@filtered";
```

Output:

```
AP WJ DS II LC BJ
```

---

To do what you actually asked for, just walk back through the array until you find a copy of the second last element, then extract all the elements that follow.

To do that, replace

```
my @filtered = reverse uniq reverse @order;
```

with

```
my $i = @order - 3;
--$i while $i >= 0 && $order[$i] ne $order[-2];
my @filtered = @order[$i+1 .. $#order];
```

Output:

```
WJ DS II LC BJ
```

As you can see, the output is different. `AP` isn't listed because they don't appear between the two instances of `LC`. So this isn't just a far more complicated approach; it's also far more fragile.